# In Cocos2d setting anchor point on a layer for pinch to zoom not working as expected

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

Right now I'm trying to implement a pinch-to-zoom feature in my Cocos2D game for iOS and I'm encountering really strange behavior. My goal is to use the handler for UIPinchGestureRecognizer to scale one of the CCNodes that represents the game level when a player pinches the screen. This has the effect of zooming.

The issue is if I set the anchor for zooming to some arbitrary value such as .5, .5 (the center of the level CCNode) it scales perfectly around the center of the level, but I want to scale around the center of the player's view. Here is what that looks like:

```
- (void) handlePinchFrom:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*) recognizer
{
if(recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
{
    _isScaling = false;
    _prevScale = 1.0;
}
else
{
    _isScaling = true;
    float deltaScale = 1.0 - _prevScale + recognizer.scale;

    // Obtain the center of the camera.
    CGPoint center = CGPointMake(self.contentSize.width/2, self.contentSize.height/2);
    CGPoint worldPoint = [self convertToWorldSpace:center];
    CGPoint areaPoint = [_area convertToNodeSpace:worldPoint];

    // Now set anchor point to where areaPoint is relative to the whole _area contentsize
    float areaLocationX = areaPoint.x / _area.contentSize.width;
    float areaLocationY = areaPoint.y / _area.contentSize.height;

    [_area moveDebugParticle:areaPoint];
    [_area setAnchorPoint:CGPointMake(areaLocationX, areaLocationY)];

    if (_area.scale*deltaScale <= ZOOM_RADAR_THRESHOLD)
    {
        _area.scale = ZOOM_RADAR_THRESHOLD;
    }
    else if (_area.scale*deltaScale >= ZOOM_MAX)
    {
        _area.scale = ZOOM_MAX;
    }
    else
    {
        // First set the anchor point.
        _area.scale *= deltaScale;
    }

    _prevScale = recognizer.scale;
}
}
```

If I set the anchor point to .5, .5 and print the calculated anchor point (areaLocationX, areaLocationY) using a CCLog it looks right, but when I set the anchor point to these values the layer scales out of control and entirely leaves the view of the player. The anchor point takes on crazy values like (-80, 10), although generally it should be relatively close to something in the range of 0 to 1 for either coordinate.

What might be causing this kind of behavior?

Comment: Does _area indeed have the content size you are expecting? A lot of times you have to set the content size of a node after setting up your scene.

Comment: It seems to have the correct content size when I debug the app. I set the content size in the _area objects init method.

Comment: I take it _area is a child of self right? Instead of converting to world space for self, try converting to node space. Or you probably can skip that and take the center and send it directly to _area for the conversion to node space.

Comment: I think the conversion is right either way (I just tried it out) because if I set the anchor point to simply be (.5, .5) (the center of the _area object) and then try the pinch-to-zoom feature it moves the debug particle to the center of the view every time. The debug particle is a CCSprite that is a child of _area. _area is a child of self. [Screenshots Here](http://imgur.com/a/U1MuD) The debug particle is the reddish dot.

Answer (score 0):

Ok it looks like I solved it. I was continually moving the anchor point -during- the scaling rather than setting it at the very beginning once. The result was really erratic scaling rather than something smooth and expected. The resolved code looks like this:

```
- (void) handlePinchFrom:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*) recognizer
{
if(recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
{
    _isScaling = false;
    _prevScale = 1.0;
}
else
{
    if (!_isScaling)
    {

        // Obtain the center of the camera.
        CGPoint center = CGPointMake(self.contentSize.width/2, self.contentSize.height/2);
        CGPoint areaPoint = [_area convertToNodeSpace:center];

        // Now set anchor point to where areaPoint is relative to the whole _area contentsize
        float anchorLocationX = areaPoint.x / _area.contentSize.width;
        float anchorLocationY = areaPoint.y / _area.contentSize.height;

        [_area moveDebugParticle:areaPoint];
        [_area setAnchorPoint:CGPointMake(anchorLocationX, anchorLocationY)];
        CCLOG(@"Anchor Point: (%f, %f)", anchorLocationX, anchorLocationY);
    }

    _isScaling = true;
    float deltaScale = 1.0 - _prevScale + recognizer.scale;

    if (_area.scale*deltaScale <= ZOOM_RADAR_THRESHOLD)
    {
        _area.scale = ZOOM_RADAR_THRESHOLD;
    }
    else if (_area.scale*deltaScale >= ZOOM_MAX)
    {
        _area.scale = ZOOM_MAX;
    }
    else
    {
        _area.scale *= deltaScale;
    }

    _prevScale = recognizer.scale;
}
}
```